# How is unfairness measured in operating systems?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, load, scheduling, starvation

In [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/821123/), in the section titled *Fairness with difficult workloads*, they talk about unfairness and quantify it on a scale that goes from 0% (best) to 50% (worst). How is that measured? What do these numbers indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfairness compares actual running time to ideal running time. If you have C cpus, T tasks and S seconds, then ideal running time for each task is

```
t(ideal) = C * S / T
```

If you have one CPU and 2 tasks, and one task gets all of the time when it should get half the time, then unfairness is 50%. As it says in the article, 50% is the worst case unfairness.